# Possible to display PDF within android offline, No SD Card, no external apps?

Tags: android, pdf, offline, android-sdcard

Hello I am trying to display a PDF file from within my android app with some restrictions.

1. Available Offline
2. No External Apps
3. No SD Card.

How can I do this?

Update: After talking to my client we have been talking about trying to display the document in a .mobi format. Unfortunately I have only been able to to find examples of displaying the ebook from a SD card.

Comment: If you have done #3 successfully, then you already have made "the SD card not a requirement".

Comment: Sorry I meant you can't use a SD card, I edited it.

Comment: Again, you say you already did #3 successfully.

Comment: Why is this tagged "PDF"? It seems irrelevant to your actual question.

Comment: I am trying to display a PDF.